# Training ML.NET -- System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, machine-learning, ml.net

First off, I am new to ML.NET (and ML as a whole).  I am trying to set up a model using a SQL Server table as my data source.  I am selecting one label and 18 features from the same table and this table contains a little more than 3 million records in it.  When I finish selecting my label/features and click on the **Train** button, I get a prompt telling me that VS will download 1.1 GB of data from the SQL Server (hosted on the same machine) which I acknowledge.  I get feedback indicating that the download is in progress and this lasts for 30 - 60 seconds.  Then I get the following error:

```
Error retrieving SQL data: "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.ToolWindows.ModelBuilderDataContext.<DownloadSqlFileAsync>b__88_0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.ToolWindows.ModelBuilderDataContext.<DownloadSqlFileAsync>d__88.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.ToolWindows.ModelBuilderDataContext.<<OnDataChanged>b__77_1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.ToolWindows.TrainTabDataContext.<BuildTrainModelParametersAsync>d__138.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.ToolWindows.TrainTabDataContext.<StartTrainingAsync>d__130.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelBuilder.ToolWindows.TrainTabControl.<<StartTraining_Click>b__5_0>d.MoveNext()
```

Some fun facts:

- I've watched the RAM count on the machine while the attempt to train is made and it's not getting above 65% of total RAM available.
- In the same VS solution, I have another app where I routinely read the entirety of the table in question into memory via EF.
- I am using VS Community and SQL Express
- I see the RAM count increase by maybe 3 or so GB before the error occurs.  It smells so badly like it's running the process in 32-bit (which would make sense of all of this) but if there's a setting for this, I can't find it.  I've checked the **Build** properties for my ML project and made sure that's set to 64-bit but I'm not sure that's even what is being used when you're training the model.

Comment: Are you using the DatabaseLoader from ML.NET to get the data?

Comment: If you are using the .net framework, try unchecking "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process"

Comment: @Jon I'm not sure...  =/  I am following this guide, which uses a UI clearly geared toward the chronically ignorant (like me):  https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/ml-dotnet/get-started-tutorial/intro

Comment: @ShakHam I am using .NET Core 2.1.  Perhaps I should try rolling that forward?

Comment: I *think* using the DatabaseLoader may be more efficient. Here's a sample for it - https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/DatabaseLoader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ModelBuilder is (necessarily) a 32-bit extension and so it cannot process as much data as I was trying to push to it.  I've opened a bug / feature request to get the data introduction into some 64-bit code or else change the way the data is ingested.

https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-modelbuilder/issues/647